# Dictionary error after check if word is correct

Tags: c#

I create dictionary with some words to be translated from English to Polish and from Polish to English. From English to Polish its works and it look like this:

```
Dictionary<string, string> myDict =
new Dictionary<string, string>();

myDict.Add("Pies", "Dog");
myDict.Add("Kot", "Cat");
myDict.Add("Swinia", "Pig");
myDict.Add("Chomik", "Hamster");
myDict.Add("Ptak", "Bird");
myDict.Add("Mysz", "Mouse");
myDict.Add("Pszczola", "Bee");
myDict.Add("Niedzwiedz", "Bear");
myDict.Add("Krowa", "Cow");
myDict.Add("Kurczak", "Chicken");
myDict.Add("Kaczka", "Duck");
myDict.Add("Slon", "Elephant");
myDict.Add("Ryba", "Fish");
myDict.Add("Zaba", "Frog");
myDict.Add("Lew", "Lion");

if (textBox2.Text == myDict[textBox1.Text])
{
    MessageBox.Show("Dobrze");
    var rnd = new Random();
    int randomValue = rnd.Next(1, 15);
    string a = myDict.Values.ElementAt(randomValue);
    textBox2.Text = a;
}
```

but from Polish to English isn't working and it look like this.

After typing a word and checking, an error pops up:

> System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException: "The given key was not underground in the dictionary."

```
Dictionary<string, string> myDict =
new Dictionary<string, string>();

myDict.Add("Pies", "Dog");
myDict.Add("Kot", "Cat");
myDict.Add("Swinia", "Pig");
myDict.Add("Chomik", "Hamster");
myDict.Add("Ptak", "Bird");
myDict.Add("Mysz", "Mouse");
myDict.Add("Pszczola", "Bee");
myDict.Add("Niedzwiedz", "Bear");
myDict.Add("Krowa", "Cow");
myDict.Add("Kurczak", "Chicken");
myDict.Add("Kaczka", "Duck");
myDict.Add("Slon", "Elephant");
myDict.Add("Ryba", "Fish");
myDict.Add("Zaba", "Frog");
myDict.Add("Lew", "Lion");

if (textBox2.Text == myDict[textBox1.Text])
{
    MessageBox.Show("Dobrze");
    var rnd = new Random();
    int randomValue = rnd.Next(1, 15);
    string b = myDict.Keys.ElementAt(randomValue);
    textBox2.Text = b;
}
```

i only change

```
string a = myDict.Values.ElementAt(randomValue);
```

to

```
string b = myDict.Keys.ElementAt(randomValue);
```

Comment: FYI, there are better ways to search for a key, such as [ContainsKey](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2.containskey?view=net-5.0).

Comment: You code assumes that whatever is in the textbox is valid to index into the dictionary in your `if`. But this assumes users are infallible. We also don't know *what you put in the textbox when you got the error*.